# Deserialize into a Singleton for App Configuration Settings

Tags: c#, serialization, singleton, deserialization

I am trying to use a Singleton backed with an XML file for my application configurations.

My Singleton looks like this:

```
public sealed class AppConfig
{
    private static readonly Lazy<AppConfig> appConfig = new(() => new AppConfig());
    public static AppConfig Settings
    {
        get { return appConfig.Value; }
    }
    private AppConfig()
    {
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

To write the contents of the Singleton to disk I can use:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppConfig));
var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);
xs.Serialize(sw, AppConfig.Settings);
```

The obvious code to read the XML file back into the Singleton results in a compile error, because of course the instance is `readonly`

```
var sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
AppConfig.Settings = (AppConfig)xs.Deserialize(sr);

Error   CS0200
Property or indexer 'AppConfig.Settings' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

An option I have found is to create another class that holds the values and make this a property of the singleton.  Then this class gets serialized, eg:

```
public sealed class AppConfig
{
    private static readonly Lazy<AppConfig> appConfig = new(() => new AppConfig());
    public static AppConfig Settings
    {
        get { return appConfig.Value; }
    }
    private AppConfig()
    {
        Values = new Values();
    }
    public Values Values { get; set; }
}
public class Values
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

To serialise/deserialise use the appropriate call on this, eg:

```
AppConfig.Settings.Values = (Values)xs.Deserialize(sr);
```

While what I have come up with works, it seems a bit convoluted, and the access path to the variables is of course longer.

Is there a better way to deserialise into the Singleton?

Is it a safe option just to remove the `readonly`?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your second solution is a variation of the [Memento Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)?

Comment: No. That's purely coincidental.  The objective is to be able to load the saved state of the singleton so as to restore its contents (at least the ones which can bel).

Comment: Why don't you have a second `private ctor`, which receives the filepath and do the deserialization there?